# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'channels')

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, discord.js

I'm trying to make an event that when someone added my bot it will send a message embed on a channel that my bot can send the message embed.

**discord.js:** v13.6.0

**Node:** v17.7.2

**events/guildCreate.js**

```
const client = require("../index");
const discord = require("discord.js")

client.on("guildCreate", async (client, guild) => {
  let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
    channel =>
      channel.type === "text" &&
      channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
  );
  channel.send( new discord.MessageEmbed()
               .setDescription("**Thank you for adding me!**")
               .setColor("#fcba03"))
})
```

edit:
I kinda of fix my problem with the reading channels:

```
const client = require("../index");
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

client.on("guildCreate", async (guild, message) => {
  let channel = guild.channels.cache.find(
    channel =>
      channel.type === "text" &&
      channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")
  );
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  embed.setDescription("Thank you for adding me!")
  embed.setColor("#2f3136")
  message.guild.channels.cache.get(channel).send(embed)
})
```

but then again got new error:
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')**

Comment: From a very quick look at the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) and the [code](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/stable/src/client/websocket/handlers/GUILD_CREATE.js#L22), it seems that the `guild` is the first and only parameter passed to the event handler

Comment: thanks, i tried to change the code to the way I look it's right for me but I got new error:
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')

Comment: Again, look at the code I linked. There is only **one** parameter passed to the event handler, the `guild`. No `message`, no `client`, just `guild`. Why would you need to access `message.guild` anyway if you already have `guild`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your “channel” is an array instead of a channel object, because you're filtering all text channels. Make sure to select the first channel of the array/collection.

Try to show what shows up when you log the “channel”